# Does Cargo.lock generation depend on the OS?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Let's say I develop a Rust application on Windows but build the release versions on (and *for*) Linux. Also, I don't have any platform-specific dependencies in my `Cargo.toml` file. I imagine the correct workflow in this case would be to let my Windows environment generate the `Cargo.lock` file, which I should put into version control (since we are talking about a *binary*, not a *lib* project) and use that file on the build server as well. I presume that it shouldn't matter whether the `Cargo.lock` file was generated in one OS or another - its contents would be the same.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: I don't know the authoritative answer to that, but I have shared a `Cargo.lock` between Windows and Linux without issue.

Comment: It is platform independent by my experience.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cargo FAQ](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries):

> ## Why do binaries have Cargo.lock in version control, but not libraries?
>
> The purpose of a Cargo.lock lockfile is to describe the state of the
> world at the time of a successful build. Cargo uses the lockfile to
> provide deterministic builds on different times and different systems,
> by ensuring that the exact same dependencies and versions are used as
> when the Cargo.lock file was originally generated.
>
> This property is most desirable from applications and packages which
> are at the very end of the dependency chain (binaries). As a result,
> it is recommended that all binaries check in their Cargo.lock.
>
> For libraries the situation is somewhat different. A library is not
> only used by the library developers, but also any downstream consumers
> of the library. Users dependent on the library will not inspect the
> library’s Cargo.lock (even if it exists). This is precisely because a
> library should not be deterministically recompiled for all users of
> the library.
>
> If a library ends up being used transitively by several dependencies,
> it’s likely that just a single copy of the library is desired (based
> on semver compatibility). If Cargo used all of the dependencies'
> Cargo.lock files, then multiple copies of the library could be used,
> and perhaps even a version conflict.
>
> In other words, libraries specify semver requirements for their
> dependencies but cannot see the full picture. Only end products like
> binaries have a full picture to decide what versions of dependencies
> should be used.

This implies that they are portable. You should add `Cargo.lock` files into your SCM software for executable projects.

Comment: This really does not answer the question. OP asks if cargo.lock contains OS specific stuff, not whether libraries should commit it to SCM.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev OP ponders putting the Cargo.lock file in SCM in the question. In any case, the fact that the docs recommend putting it in SCM strongly suggests that it is a portable format (and it is - it's just TOML).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, I had read that part of the docs. And indeed, the fact that the docs recommend putting the `Cargo.lock` file into version control made me presume that it should *not* matter from which OS it's generated. But I didn't see it stated explicitly, hence the question posted here. I'm looking for a confirmation. As for the TOML format - I don't see how that's relevant. Any text format will be portable. It's the **contents** of the generated file that matters, not its format.

Comment: @at54321 I don't know if there is any text explicitly and specifically stating that it's portable. I can tell you that there are executable crates on crates.io that work on both platforms - something that would not be possible if they were non-portable. I can also tell you that I can work on my same projects on Windows and Linux with the same Cargo.lock.

Comment: Seems like an easy test would be to just build on each platform and compare the results. If I build on Linux, the generated `Cargo.lock` contains dependencies for `winapi` and `kernel32-sys`, which obviously would not actually be used on Linux.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo note that executable crates on crates.io ignore the `Cargo.lock` file even if it is present (in fact [`cargo install` ignores the lock file by default](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7169) for all executable crates).

Comment: @jmb why is that still the case despite that being the whole point of package locking? It should be opt-out, not opt-in as it is right now.

Comment: @Kaihaku I agree. I think the argument is that this allows user to pick up security updates to the libraries automatically, but that seems a weak argument to me (proper support for dynamic linking would be a much better solution).